# CreateLogger() was previously called and can only be called once

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration, .net-5, serilog

I get the following exception:

> CreateLogger() was previously called and can only be called once.

I don't know when `CreateLogger()` was called twice.

My Configuration like this:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
                Log.Information("Starting host...");
                host.Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "Host terminated unexpectedly."); //HERE IS THE EXCEPTION: CreateLogger() was previously called and can only be called once.
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    webBuilder.UseSerilog((provider, context, loggerConfig) =>
                    {
                        loggerConfig.Configure(provider, Configuration);
                    });
                });
```

---

My extension Method in called library:

```
  public static void Configure(this LoggerConfiguration loggerConfig,
        IServiceProvider provider, IConfiguration config)
        {
            var sqlserverConnectionString = config["ConnectionStrings:S1"];
            var sqlserverLogTable = config["Logging:S2"];
            var rollingFileName = config["Logging:S3"];

            var sinkOpts = new MSSqlServerSinkOptions();
            sinkOpts.TableName = sqlserverLogTable;
            sinkOpts.AutoCreateSqlTable = true;
            var columnOpts = new ColumnOptions();
            columnOpts.Store.Remove(StandardColumn.Properties);
            columnOpts.Store.Add(StandardColumn.LogEvent);
            columnOpts.LogEvent.DataLength = 2048;
            columnOpts.PrimaryKey = columnOpts.TimeStamp;
            columnOpts.TimeStamp.NonClusteredIndex = true;


            loggerConfig
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .Enrich.WithMachineName()
                .Enrich.WithAssemblyName()
                .Enrich.WithAssemblyVersion()
                .Enrich.WithAspnetcoreHttpcontext(provider, GetContextInfo)
                .WriteTo.File(rollingFileName)
               .WriteTo.MSSqlServer(
                    connectionString: sqlserverConnectionString,
                    sinkOptions: sinkOpts,
                    columnOptions: columnOpts
                ).CreateLogger();
        }
```

Comment: Do you actually need to call `CreateLogger` here? You don't need to create a logger since you're only configuring it. Just remove that line.

Comment: @DavidG should I don’t call it here, based on the doc this’s how i configure serilog

Comment: Only if you need the logger object to write to the log during the configuration cycle. Remove it and see what happens...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`UseSerilog` calls `CreateLogger` internally](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/blob/v4.1.0/src/Serilog.AspNetCore/SerilogWebHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L107)... So either:

- Do not call CreateLogger yourself and let `UseSerilog` do it for you
- Use a different overload for `UseSerilog` where you give it the `ILogger` that you create yourself

Answer (score 1):

@C. Augusto Proiete already explained in short... and this is some [detail](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L183) if your want to take a look.

Your code get execute at line 183, cause `useReload` variable should be null as if you doesn't do anything to the logger, the variable `reloadable` should be false, as it originally evaluate as `ReloadableLogger reloadable = Log.Logger as ReloadableLogger;` (what is behind the screen that's not showing directly on that file)